# PC turns on for second

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, gpu

I bought a pc with the following spec like 1 nd a half year back!

```
Processor : Intel Core i5 2500
MotherBoard : Intel DH67BL
RAM : G-Skill RipjawsX 4GB
HDD : 500GB Samsung
Graphics Card : EVGA Geforce 560 ti
PSU : Silverstone Strider Pure 600W
```

Now today, I removed my side panel of the computer to switch off some LED lights in my Casing. While doing that I accidentally touched part of my GPU. ( The PC was switched on nd I was stupid to do it ) Suddenly the PC shutdown. ( I've experienced this previously too ) So I switched off the current supply to my pc and waited for 10 mins. Then cleared my BIOS Settings and restarted the PC. But when I push the power button, I noticed that my processor fan and the GPU fan rotate for a second and turned off. I switched off the PSU from the switch it has and waited a while nd did the same thing! But as previously The CPU did no turn on.

I tried to turn on the machine with the GPU removed and it turn on as normal. Nothing wrong with it! All works well.

Now my question is, can it be something wrong with my GPU or the PSU maybe! I know I touched the GPU but, since it turns on for a second I have the feeling that my PSU is not giving enough power to switch on the PC with the GPU. Please give me any suggestion I should do to determine where the fault is!

Thank you.

Comment: Its very possible you introduced an `Electrostatic Discharge` event into your system. If this happened, its very likely, at the very least your graphics card was damaged. At this point until you replace the graphics card there isn't much we can suggest. **In the future DO NOT open your case with the system running** you have learned the expensive and good lesson of the dangers of `ESD`. Here is a good read about ESD: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge

Comment: Thank you for your comment! :) YEah I've learned a lesson the hard way! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely touching the sides of the video card won't do anything bad (unless you hit the fan or something). However, if you touched some of the circuitry, without following proper [electrostatic discharge](http://www.devhardware.com/c/a/Computer-Systems/A-Computer-Builders-Guide-to-ESD/) (ESD) precautions, like grounding yourself, using an antistatic wrist strap, and working on an antistatic mat, there is a *possibility* that you may have had an ESD, which may very well cause erratic behavior of the GPU and/or other components. Granted, the possibility is low, but this is often overlooked. Troubleshooting for this issue is very difficult, and in most cases the components are unsalvageable.

One thing you may want to try before getting a new GPU: turn the PSU off with the switch, and disconnect the power cord. Wait a while, then hook it back up and try again. The reason for this is that most PSU's store a charge, even when they're switched off and still connected to a power source. Cycling the power may help.

Did the PC work normally before with that configuration? Although you said that this has happened before, I believe that PSU would be sufficient for the power requirements of that card, though you should look into other factors like the current requirements of the card and the power for other components. Here is a [good article](http://www.guru3d.com/articles_pages/evga_geforce_gtx_560_ti_2win_review,7.html) about a similar card (although it's the 2Win version). If the PSU is under powered for the system, the computer may not start, or may cause lockups, shutdowns etc. You may want to look into the [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-testhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) codes.

From your troubleshooting I think it's most likely the GPU. Sorry pal.